# Cannot insert NULL into column 'UserId'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am using Entity Framework and this model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string first_name_1 { get; set; }

    public int? location_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("location_id")]
    public virtual Location location  { get; set; }  

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string telephone_no_1 { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser applicationuser { get; set; }
}
```

This is the context I am using

```
public class CustomContext: DbContext
{
    public RegistryContext() : base("name=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContextName"])
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<RegistryContext, registry_services.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<registry_services.Models.User> Users { get; set; }

    public int GetNextSequenceValue(string sequenceName)
    {
        var rawQuery = Database.SqlQuery<int>($"SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR {sequenceName};");
        var task = rawQuery.SingleAsync();
        int nextVal = task.Result;

        return nextVal;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

        // Your configuration goes here
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

> Cannot insert NULL into column 'UserId' table AspNetUsers while executing update-database command

Below is the object for USER in the `Seed` method:-

```
        new Models.User
        {
            id = 4,
            first_name_1 = "Nick",

            location_id = 3,

            UserId = "67639413-9e42-4eef-9292-bd66527f91bf"**// this is ID of one of the records in AspNetUsers Table**
        },
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Entity Framework, your column 'UserId' in your database must allow null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use Asp.Net Identity,
First of all your *CustomContext* should inherits from **IdentityDbContext** class instead of DbContext. Secondly, your  *User* class should inherits from **IdentityUser** class.

Try it, probably resolve your problem.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}



public class CustomContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public CustomContext(DbContextOptions<CustomContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```